# how to destroy last two previous visited activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, destroy

For example I have four activity A, B, C, and D. I go from A to B and from B to C and then from C to D.
Now in Activity D, on particular button click, I want to destroy Activity D as well as activity C and want to jump on activity B. Now when I click on back button in activity B, then it should navigate me on activity A. please help someone how can I achieve this functionality.
Note: I do not want to destroy activity C while navigating from activity C to activity D

Comment: We need https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example from your for help you.

Answer (score 0):

In `D`, when you want to navigate back to `B`, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this. ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will cause A and D to be removed from the stack, B will now be shown in whatever state it was in when you left it, and `onNewIntent()` will be called on `B`.